# Ethernet Failed on Realtek RTL8101/2/6E 14.04 - 15.10

Tags: 14.04, drivers, ethernet, 15.10, realtek

Ok, I've tried to follow every example I could find but nothing is working. I need your help. One day an update came along and I lost my ethernet. A failed version upgrade eventually resulted in a reinstall of 15.04, then I upgraded to 15.10. In each version I have tried to download the current Realtek RTL8101E driver (I've also tried r8169 from the realtek site). I can get the r8101 module loaded but I can't even ping my router with the wired connection. Wireless IS running on the ath9k driver. Here is some detailed info:

```
ryan@hplaptop:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for ryan: 
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:fd:52:ec:e9:fd
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.2.0-18-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2500000-c257ffff memory:c2580000-c258ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 2c:44:fd:b3:58:42
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8101 driverversion=1.027.00-NAPI duplex=full latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:24 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c2404000-c2404fff memory:c2400000-c2403fff



ryan@hplaptop:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: i915
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM75 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
DeviceName: Atheros AR9485 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company AR9485/HB125 802.11bgn 1×1 Wi-Fi Adapter
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
DeviceName: Hanksville 10/100 Lan Connection
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1854
Kernel driver in use: r8101




ryan@hplaptop:~$ modinfo r8101
filename:       /lib/modules/4.2.0-18-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8101.ko       
version:        1.027.00-NAPI
license:        GPL
description:    RealTek RTL-8101 Fast Ethernet driver
author:         Realtek and the Linux r8101 crew <netdev@vger.kernel.org>
srcversion:     D389B0DAED4F28B777AF883
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008136sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        
vermagic:       4.2.0-18-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           speed:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8).(ushort)
parm:           duplex:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8). (int)
parm:           autoneg:force phy operation. Deprecated by ethtool (8). (int)
parm:           aspm:Enable ASPM. (int)
parm:           s5wol:Enable Shutdown Wake On Lan. (int)
parm:           rx_copybreak:Copy breakpoint for copy-only-tiny-frames (int)
parm:           timer_count:Timer Interrupt Interval. (int)
parm:           eee_enable:Enable Energy Efficient Ethernet. (int)
parm:           hwoptimize:Enable HW optimization function. (ulong)
parm:           debug:Debug verbosity level (0=none, ..., 16=all) (int)


ryan@hplaptop:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback



ryan@hplaptop:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.1.1
search charter.com


ryan@hplaptop:~$ sudo ifup eth0
Ignoring unknown interface eth0=eth0.

ryan@hplaptop:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

ryan@hplaptop:~$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable

ryan@hplaptop:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
connect: Network is unreachable

"sudo dhclient eth0" results in bringing up eth0 but there is still no connection however now I get some different results:

ryan@hplaptop:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0

ryan@hplaptop:~$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
ryan@hplaptop:~$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     1002   0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0

ryan@hplaptop:~$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.8.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.8.2 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Thank you to anyone who can help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while Installing Driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076932/error-while-installing-driver)

Answer (score 0):

> sudo dhclient

This command will help repair it completely if you have used Tethering softwares many times or hotspots etc. I got this command from another post. This worked for me

But First, type, this will help you find out how your hardware is registered on your system. Look for the first one in the first block, for example mine was called enp3s0.

> ifconfig

Otherwise look for this article's last comment [Realtek ethernet driver error ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770368/realtek-ethernet-driver-error-ubuntu-16-04)
Note: Try this one first