# Realtek ethernet driver error ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, ethernet, realtek

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04. when i was using 15.10 ethernet works flawlessly. But after upgrading to 16.04 it doesn't work anymore showing network cable unplugged. I tried reinstalling driver & end up getting following error

```
sumit@Lenovo-Z50-70:~/Desktop/r8168-8.041.01$ sudo ./autorun.sh
[sudo] password for sumit:

Check old driver and unload it.
rmmod r8169
Build the module and install
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

When i had installed in 15.10 it was installed successfully.
My ethernet controller is: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev10).
I have done all proxy settings same as they were in 15.10.

Please help. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get an internet connection(i got through wifi). Use the command:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

Enter your password. This will install the latest version of the driver. Ethernet connection should be established after installing (you may reboot & check again).

Answer (score 4):

For product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
the above solution didn't work. I had to download driver from [here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2) and install with `./autorun.sh`.

After that I still couldn't connect to the internet. But the r8101 kernel module was loaded and in nm the connection came up. I noticed there was no mac address. With the following command I forced a random chosen mac address.

```
sudo ifconfig enp3s0 hw ether 00:04:FE:11:22:38
```

where enp3s0 was my ethernet nic.
with this I got my internet connection but is wasn't persistent.
I had to add

```
pre-up ifconfig enp3s0 hw ether 00:04:FE:11:22:38
```

at the end of `/etc/network/interfaces` file

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Comment: I have been wrestling with this problem for a really long while. Thank you so much, that really helped :) 
I did the exact same thing but changed "enp3s0" to the name "enp0s31f6" that I found by typing "ifconfig"

Comment: I have the same `RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller` and tried the above method. Still my connection is not persistent. There is a packet loss if I do a ping `165 packets transmitted, 163 received, 1% packet loss, time 164241ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.053/11.794/131.199/16.516 ms`. What can be a further debugging I can perform to solve this problem?

Comment: The driver page only servers a driver for kernel 4.7, how can i get this running on Ubuntu 16.04 with kernel 4.8?