# r8168 module not used by ethernet controller

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, ethernet

I discovered that my eth0 interface is constantly down (I use wlan0 for WiFi). After some googling I replaced r8169 module with r8168 (`apt-get install r8168-dkms`), but after rebooting failed to find the 'Kernel driver in use' line:

```
root@controller:/home/me# lspci -v

07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 01-00-00-00-36-4c-e0-00
Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
```

Here's output from `dkms status`:

```
root@controller:/home/me# dkms status
oem-audio-hda-daily, 0.201409230816~ubuntu14.04.1, 3.13.0-106-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics, 0.5wataugafour1, 3.13.0-106-generic, x86_64: installed
oem-touchpad-alps-synaptics, 0.5wataugafour1, 4.4.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
r8168, 8.043.02, 4.4.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
wireless-dw1707-precise-all, 3.12rc5p5, 3.5.0-61-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Also:

```
root@controller:/home/me# lshw -C NETWORK
USB                       
*-network        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: a8:a7:95:b5:dd:f9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-57-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.57 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:18 memory:f7d00000-f7d7ffff memory:f7d80000-f7d8ffff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7c00000-f7c00fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
*-network DISABLED
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: virbr0-nic
   serial: 52:54:00:71:16:c9
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=tun driverversion=1.6 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Mbit/s
```

Also:

```
root@controller:/home/me# modinfo r1869
modinfo: ERROR: Module r1869 not found.
```

Now eth0 interface is absent in the `ifconfig -a` output, probably because r8168 wasn't detected at startup.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong or forgot? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `modinfo r1869` should be `modinfo r8169`.

Comment: You should not make massive changes to a question after it has been answered. Please post a new question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS. Ubuntu will not load unsigned kernel modules with this enabled.

edit:

The r8168-dkms is not the right driver for your Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07).

To uninstall it:

`sudo dkms remove r8168/8.043.02 --all` # to uninstall r8168 kernel module

`sudo apt-get purge r8168-dkms` # to uninstall r8168-dkms

Make sure that the file `/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf` does not exist.

Reboot the computer.

Edit your question to include the `terminal` output of the first 3 lines of `modinfo r8169`, and `sudo lshw -C network`

You will have to download the rtl8101 driver from http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

[image]

Follow the instructions in the README file contained in the download file, and review this [Realtek ethernet driver error ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770368/realtek-ethernet-driver-error-ubuntu-16-04/802459#802459) (*starting with the answer that contains "For product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express"*).

Comment: Hi heynemma! I tried this, but with no results - still no eth0 and r8168 not seems to be used by the controller.

Comment: @edwardziyangulov Edit your question to include the `terminal` app output of the command `dkms status`.

Comment: Follow the PENDING instructions in my answer, and STOP where it says stop here.

Comment: You're a magician! :) I've run the `./autorun.sh`, and now I see my eth0 interface in `ifconfig`.

Comment: I'm a newbie to AskUbuntu, what can I do for you - raise your rating, etc.?

Comment: In my case, sudo apt-get autoremove was needed as well. Now the troubles caused by r8168 are fixed, thank you!