# No internet access in Dell precision 3660 works station with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, internet, ethernet

I have had no internet access in my new PC in the lab with Ubuntu 22.04 since day one. I looked up similar problem on internet. Tried many things. This (https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=366982) seems to be a problem similar to mine. There seems to be lot of discussion about netowrk adapter drivers ([r8168/r8169 - which one should I use?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1279644/r8168-r8169-which-one-should-i-use)). I am buying a WIFI card to temporarily resolve the issue. Any help in this matter is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with Dell Precision 3660 and was able to fix it by doing the following:
[Remapped hard drive to new PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1500568/remapped-hard-drive-to-new-pc/1500573#1500573).