# Remapped hard drive to new PC

Tags: networking, kernel

I have a PC that was remapped so as to keep the same setup. An alternative was converting to a VM.

The ethernet networking does not work and I cannot connect to anything. When lshw -C network is run, it outputs:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet controller
    product: Intel Corporation
    vendor: Intel Corporation
    physical id: 1f.6
    bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
    version: 11
    width: 32 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:72380000-7239ffff
```

I have tried and run dpkg -i on linux-modules, linux-modules-extra, linux-headers, linux-headers-generic-hwe for the right kernel version, which is 5.4.0-150 on amd64. All of that did not work. The Ubuntu version is 18.04.1.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is out of standard support, so this question is off-topic here. Upgrading to a current release of Ubuntu would in all likelihood have given you the recent driver version and solved the issue.

Comment: Cannot upgrade yet due to using it as a toolchain build machine and having dozens of dependencies that would disappear.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this issue by updating the driver for the Intel ethernet controller. To find the correct driver, I had to look for the specific device that I had and find the owner's manual (https://dl.dell.com/content/manual60259583-precision-3660-tower-setup-and-specifications.pdf?language=en-us). Mine happened to be a Dell Precision 3660 tower. The manual stated that the ethernet controller model number was Intel I219-LM. Looking on Intel forums I was able to find the correct driver which happened to be e1000e. I happened to have this driver already installed and I knew I did by running:

```
modinfo e1000e
```

But it was an older version. So I downloaded the tarball from https://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20historic%20archive/ put the tarball onto a flash drive and moved it to the problematic PC. Then I opened the archive and followed the directions in the README to MANUALLY install the driver. However, BEFORE installing the driver, I backed up my old one by just doing a sudo cp to a directory. Then I ran into an issue installing it because it was unsigned and I found the solution to be disabling SecureBoot in the computer BIOS. Once that was done I was able to get it working upon rebooting the PC.