# eth0 interface is DOWN with r8101 Ethernet driver

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

I've got Ubuntu 16.04 and the kernel modul r8101 running my Ethernet controller. My problem is that my interface eth0 is always in a DOWN state, `dmesg | eth0` shows

```
root@controller:~# dmesg | grep eth0
[  679.680412] eth0: Identified chip type is 'RTL8106E'.
[  693.990288] eth0: 0xffffc90000d24000, 20:47:47:4e:3d:82, IRQ 46
[  694.136398] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[21725.426834] device eth0 entered promiscuous mode
[22601.427648] brq93fbe497-9e: port 1(eth0) entered disabled state
[22604.329345] eth0: 0xffffc90000d24000, 20:47:47:4e:3d:82, IRQ 46
[22604.469793] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[23015.888641] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[23727.415453] brq93fbe497-9e: port 1(eth0) entered disabled state
[23733.953087] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[23733.953452] eth0: 0xffffc90000d24000, 20:47:47:4e:3d:82, IRQ 46
[23734.076573] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[23744.937540] brq93fbe497-9e: port 1(eth0) entered disabled state
[23747.916793] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[23747.917751] eth0: 0xffffc90000d24000, 20:47:47:4e:3d:82, IRQ 46
[23748.042896] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
```

I've already tried editing /etc/network/interfaces, running the `ifconfig eth0 up` command with NetworkManager switched off - with no result.

I'm using wlan0 interface for WiFi, but I also need eth0 for bridging virtual interfaces.

Is there anything I can do with it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps disabling bridging long enough to resolve the situation with eth0 would be useful. Then again, you may be impacted by [thjis bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/1255516)

Comment: OK, I deleted all virtualized networks and tried againg to bring up eth0 with `ifconfig eth0 up` - it didn't work.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of  `sudo lshw -C Network`

Comment: Someone solved a similar issue by [downloading and installing a r8101 driver](http://askubuntu.com/a/802459/338446).