# Ubuntu 16.10 Can't connect to internet (Cable nor wireless)

Tags: networking, internet, 16.10

I've been looking all around and I can't find a solution.

I had to run a package repair on my ubuntu 16.10 because it was stopping at the loading screen. After that I was able to log in, however I couldn't connect to the Internet anymore.

Also, It's a dual boot with a Windows 10. And I can connect to the internet through it and other devices.

I've seen many solutions saying that an update would do the trick, and people who could connect one way or the way were able to fix it. But since I can't I don't know what to do.

I've seen that people would usually ask for the same information, so here they are.

output of `ifconfig`

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1772  bytes 96280 (96.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1772  bytes 96280 (96.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0d  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 30
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f7200000-f73fffff
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Ethernet controller
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 0c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7400000-f7400fff memory:f2100000-f2103fff
```

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What is the response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe r8169`?

Comment: I got this response:

`Module r8169 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic
`

Comment: Can you boot into an earlier kernel version at the GRUB menu if you reboot? If so, I suspect that the wireless and ethernet *both* work as expected. You have all the signs of a badly flawed update or else original install.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much! Would you mind answering the question so I can choose it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. I installed a different wireless driver, than my wireless adapter required. After that, my `iwconfig` showed the same. No wireless extensions.

What you got there is loopback interface, which I don't know, why you haven't got there the wireless one as well, but try this. I fixed my problem by installing same kernel version that I got. That fixed and reinstalled some crucial things inside, and now everything works again.

Try it, but of course **use your version of kernel, or that one you want!**

In case you will use older version, you system might become unstable. If you will use the same one, the system will most probably, just reinstall the incorrect software, for that version of kernel, with correct ones.

```
sudo apt install <version of your kernel>
```

Look up your version of kernel, on the Internet.

Comment: Yeah, this was the idea behind chili555 answer. Since he/she never posted as an answer (besides the commentary), I'm choosing yours as the correct.

Answer (score 0):

'Unclaimed' typically means no driver has attached to the specific hardware.
For the wired network maybe the solution could be found here: [Realtek ethernet driver error ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770368/realtek-ethernet-driver-error-ubuntu-16-04)
with:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

YOu can install this by downloading the package from another computer/boot-session unsing the URL:

```
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb
```

Other Links can be found here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/xenial/all/r8168-dkms/download

Copy the package to an USB flash drive.
Go to your Ubuntu Linux installation, plugin the USB Flash drive.
You should see the mount on

```
/media/your_user_id/uuid-of-the-drive
```

use the command

```
sudo apt install PATH_TO_THE_DEB_FILE
```

to install the package. There could be dependencies to other packages. If so, please check ask Ubuntu for informations to resolve this (without internet access).

After a reboot you should be able to use your wired ethernet.

Comment: How might he do that with no internet at all?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't run this, because I don't have internet, do you know anyway I could get it and then install it manually? I also tried Filip's solution to download the driver from the link and then using ./autorun.sh, but I got this:
`Check old driver and unload it.
 Build the module and install
 make[2]: *** /lib/modules/4.8.0-46-generic/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
 make[1]: *** [clean] Error 2
 make: *** [clean] Error 2`

Answer (score 0):

Check witch module is missing

```
lspci -nn | grep Network
```

maybe try to reload it, maybe `wl`

```
sudo modprobe -r <name module>
sudo modprobe <name module>
```

Then check if the module is maybe blacklisted. Then let start the module at boot. Reboot.

Comment: I got the following response from the 

lspci -nn | grep Network command

`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 30)`

I suppose this was not the droid, I mean, response I was looking for...

Comment: try these to get the loaded kernel driver/module

    `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net`