# Error while Installing Driver

Tags: drivers, software-installation, realtek

I downloaded Driver for Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller from their site : http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=7&PFid=7&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2

IT is saved in "Downloads" folder

> Went through the "readme" which said
>
> Unpack the tarball :      # tar vjxf r8101-1.aaa.bb.tar.bz2
>
> Change to the directory:        # cd r8101-1.aaa.bb

When I ran the command

```
tar vjxf r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2
```

It gave the following error :

```
tar (child): r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I then tried to change the directory to "r8101-1.033.00" :

```
cd r8101-1.033.00
```

and it gave back :

```
 bash: cd: r8101-1.033.00: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong ? how should I do it ?

Comment: Did you `cd ~/Downloads` first? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: No i did not, but I manually opened the downloads folder, and ran terminal form there too. Does it makes a difference ?

Comment: It certainly does. If the file downloaded to Downloads, then you need to direct the terminal there: `cd ~/Downloads` It doesn't matter where the file browser GUI is situated. The terminal has no way to know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually search for the 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 archive (LINUX driver for kernel up to 4.10) and drag this archive's icon from the file manager into the terminal to show the full path to it. The full path to 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 is everything in the path except for 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 itself which is the archive's correct name.

Change directories using `cd` to the full path that you previously noted and run this command:

```
tar vjxf 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 # the archive's correct name is 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2
```

When you have changed directories using `cd` to the directory containing 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 you can check that you are in the correct directory by running `ls`. The results of `ls` should show that 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 is contained in the current working directory, so the command `tar vjxf 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2` will be successful since 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 is accessible from the current working directory.

When you extract the contents of 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2 it extracts them to a directory named r8101-1.033.00 which contains instructions for the next steps in the *readme* file.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Actually I omitted 0010 part that you typed in bold, and it still worked. any clue ?

Comment: The `tar vjxf r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2` command showed the same error message as in your question when I tried it, but the `tar vjxf 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2` command worked when I tried it.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @karel , I typed 0010, but overlooked :/

Answer (score 0):

From the file I downloaded, your file name is wrong.

After moving in to the directory that you downloaded to, it should be `tar vjxf 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2`

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is a 0010 before -r8101. but the instruction that realtek gave did not contain that part. so I chose to omit it.

Comment: @Spectra - You can't just omit things. If it's in the file you downloaded, you need it in the command. The instructions Realtek gave were for reference.

Comment: My bad sorry. But I omitted that part and it worked, I think. I am editing my original post.

Comment: @Spectra Don't worry. This is how we learn.

Let's start again.
Run the following: `cd ~/Downloads` then `tar vjxf 0010-r8101-1.033.00.tar.bz2`. Has it extracted the tar? (it will be in a folder named 0010-r8101-1.033.00)

Comment: Ummmmmmm....My big big bad...sorry Lewis, actually I typed 0010 and did not see it. :/